# Decode byte array to bitmap that has been compressed in Java

Tags: java, android, bitmap, compression, arrays

I am compressing a bitmap in the following way

```
Bitmap bmpSig = getMyBitMap();
int size = bmpSig.getWidth() * bmpSig.getHeight();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
bmpSig.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);   
byte[] bytSig = out.toByteArray();
```

I am then trying to display the image in an Android ImageView from the byte array. When I do this I get an image that is completely black image.

```
ImageView myImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
myImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytSig, 0, bytSig.length));
```

I'm assuming it's because I am missing a step before BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() to reverse the jpeg compression. Or have I misunderstood how the compression works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't realise that the background of my bitmap (from a Canvas object) was transparent. Since this bitmap is just black lines on a white background the black image is due to compressing to JPEG giving the image a black background.

I have changed

```
bmpSig.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

to

```
bmpSig.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

And it is working as expected.

Comment: Nah ... you just needed to use a darker shade of black.